# Copy NSMutableArray into array of floats for GLES rendering

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es

I have an **NSMutableArray** called mVerticies stored as a member of my class and I'd like to place them into a float array to draw them with *glVertexAttribPointer*.

Normally when drawing, I would have something like:

```
float verticies[] = {-1, -1, 1, -1};

// ... prepare to draw

glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition,
    2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, verticies);

// ... draw
```

But in order to use the *glVertexAttribPointer* function, i need a float[].  The verticies are stored as an **NSMutableArray** because they change quite often.  Is there an easy way to either store a dynamic float[] as a member or to quickly convert an **NSMutableArray** to a float[]?

Comment: I presume the values are stored as NSNumbers right now?

Comment: I have a follow-up question for this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21057547/how-to-copy-values-from-nsmutablearray-into-array-of-floats-to-be-used-in-opengl

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming the values are stored as NSNumbers, you can do something like this:

```
float *floatsArray = malloc([numbersArray count] * sizeof(float));
if (floatsArray == NULL) {
    // handle error
}
[numbersArray enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent usingBlock:^(NSNumber *number, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    floatsArray[idx] = [number floatValue];
}];

// use floatsArray

free(floatsArray);
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked... although it also reaffirmed my opinion that Objective-C is ugly.

Comment: Hey Andrew, would you mind helping me out with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21057547/how-to-copy-values-from-nsmutablearray-into-array-of-floats-to-be-used-in-opengl

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `malloc` if you just want a raw chunk memory to read and write values directly.

If you have an NSArray `array` containing NSNumber instances:

```
float *vertices = malloc(sizeof(float) * [array count]);
for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) {
    vertices[i] = [[array objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
}

// draw cool 3D objects and stuff
glVertexAttribPointer(....)

// then, when you're totally done with the memory
free(vertices);
```

Unlike Objective-C objects, the `vertices` pointer doesn't have a retain count, so you need to free it yourself, and keep track of when you can free it, because when you call free it will be gone immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through the values. Assuming your floats are stored as NSNumbers:

```
NSUInteger count = [mutableVerticesArray count];
float vertices[count];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    vertices[i] = [[mutableVerticesArray objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
}
// Drawing etc.
```