# How to copy values from NSMutableArray into array of floats to be used in OpenGL

Tags: objective-c, arrays, xcode, pointers, opengl

Following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285559/copy-nsmutablearray-into-array-of-floats-for-gles-rendering), I saw an alternative way to initialize the values of an array which works for my situation. I can't use the standard `float *simpleArray = {1.0f, 2.0f}` because this array needs to be have global scope, and it also needs to be initialized after several variables that can't be initialized at the global-level (object pointers). I tried implementing [one method from the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285559/copy-nsmutablearray-into-array-of-floats-for-gles-rendering/9285602#9285602) like this on a simpler example which doesn't involve a second array.

```
float *simpleArray = malloc(_numVerts * sizeof(float));
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    simpleArray[i] = i * 5.0f;
}
```

However, when I go to access the values from this array, I don't get what I want, as shown in this screenshot. And it doesn't work for OpenGL when I place the array inside either. I'm not getting an error, but none of my vertices are being drawn: [image: screenshot]

However-however, when I do this, I can access the values that I want from the array, and I see that they were placed in the array:

```
float *x = &simpleArray[0];
float *y = &simpleArray[1];
float *z = &simpleArray[2];
```

That's great and all, but it doesn't help me with OpenGL, and I don't know how the OP from the linked thread did it. Maybe I am doing something wrong on this level, or it's something I'm doing wrong with OpenGL, so here is exactly what I'm trying to do, going off of the OpenGL template provided by XCode:

In the interface:

```
@property(nonatomic) GLfloat *glCubeVertexData;
```

In the implementation:

```
#define STRIDE (NSUInteger) 6
```

Later...

```
_glCubeVertexData = malloc(_numVerts * sizeof(GLfloat));
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < _numVerts; i+= STRIDE)
{
    _glCubeVertexData[i + 0] = (GLfloat)[[[_ndVerts objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];
    _glCubeVertexData[i + 1] = (GLfloat)[[[_ndVerts objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];
    _glCubeVertexData[i + 2] = (GLfloat)[[[_ndVerts objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:2] floatValue];
    _glCubeVertexData[i + 3] = (GLfloat) 0.0f;
    _glCubeVertexData[i + 4] = (GLfloat) 0.0f;
    _glCubeVertexData[i + 5] = (GLfloat) 0.0f;
}
```

Inside `setUpGL`

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(_glCubeVertexData), _glCubeVertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

And I can see in `_ndVerts` that my vertices are exactly what they need to be, but the vertices in `_glCubeVertexData` are not being drawn at all, as if they weren't even contained in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't 100% clear to me, but you seem to be a little confused about pointers and the debugger. The array access notation in C works such that the following two lines are equivalent:

```
float x = simpleArray[i];
float x = *(simpleArray + i);
```

The code that you say works seems unlikely to be what you actually want. Instead of getting the values in the array, you're getting pointers to values in the array. You've got:

```
float *x = &simpleArray[0];
```

This reduces to:

```
float *x = (simpleArray + 0);
```

Presumably you don't want a pointer to the value though, you want the value itself:

```
float x = simpleArray[0];
```

It seems like your main confusion is that you don't see what you expect in the debugger. You've declared `simpleArray` as a pointer to a float, and pointed it to (the beginning of) a block of memory allocated with `malloc()`. The debugger is simply showing you the value of the pointer (ie. the address of the beginning of the `malloc()`ed block), along with the dereferenced pointer (ie. the *value* of the first float in the array), which is 0 exactly as you'd expect. In other words, your screenshot shows nothing amiss or unexpected at all.

As for your OpenGL vertexes not being drawn, I can't provide much advice there, as I have no experience whatsoever with OpenGL, but I suspect the problem has nothing to do with the low-level semantics of array access that you're asking about.